# Where is virsh save directory location defined

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, debian-stretch, virsh, libvirt-guests

The default location of the `virsh save myVm` goes into `/var/lib/something` which makes my slash partition full on a Vm save, which is really anoying.

I could not figure out **where is the `virsh save myVm` directory location defined**! The default is into `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save` which doesn't seem to be defined in the `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` which defines only `auto_dump_path`.

I couldn't find it neither into the `virsh edit myVm` XML, nor into the pool `virsh pool-dumpxml myPool` my VM belongs to.

It could be explained in the [redhat comunity](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/301353) I'm not a member.

Comment: The Red Hat "pay wall" hides the text *"At the moment, there is no such option in any configuration file."* with regards to changing the save location .... It suggest using the default location as a mount point to prevent your root disk from filling up

Comment: I have the entirety of `/var/lib/libvirt` separated, so as to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: @HermanB thx for the message, I think that should be an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 1):

As a **workaround but NOT THE SOLUTION** either `save` or other data could be relocated like that:

```
#supposing my /data partition is into another disk
mkdir /data/data/qemu_saved_files
chown -R libvirt-qemu:libvirt-qemu /data/data/qemu_saved_files
rm -r /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save
ln -s /data/data/qemu_saved_files /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```